# Reinhard tone mapping and color space

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, hdr

I found two ways of doing tone mapping ([first](http://www.nutty.ca/?page_id=352&link=hdr), [second](http://www.ceng.metu.edu.tr/~akyuz/files/hdrgpu.pdf)):

```
//Ld - this part of the code is the same for both versions
float lum = dot(rgb, vec3(0.2126f, 0.7152f, 0.0722f));
float L = (scale / averageLum) * lum;
float Ld = (L * (1.0 + L / lumwhite2)) / (1.0 + L);
//first
vec3 xyY = RGBtoxyY(rgb);
xyY.z *= Ld;
rgb = xyYtoRGB(xyY);
//second
rgb = (rgb / lum) * Ld;
```

For an example pixel data above equations produces different results. Which way is correct ?

Comment: What is being asked here?

Comment: Which way looks better, go with that =)

Comment: Background on what tone mapping is and what your goal is would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With tone mapping, there is no "correct" answer.  You're trying to reduce an HDR image to an LDR one that somehow visually represents the luminance range present in the original, which is very subjective.  Choosing a tone mapping equation is a matter of aesthetic judgement, not physics.

By the way, if you're interested in tone mapping, I would recommend also looking at the equation presented in John Hable's talk, [Uncharted 2 HDR Lighting](http://www.slideshare.net/ozlael/hable-john-uncharted2-hdr-lighting) (slide 140 has the equation I'm talking about).